# Как приложениям в ubuntu передать url браузеру?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, url

Пользуюсь Ubuntu 16.04 и Google Chrome. 
Когда какое-то приложение требует открыть окно браузера, передавая ему url, браузер открывает пустую страницу. С другими браузерами все в порядке.

- check_common_commands http://ya.ru
- '[' 1 -gt 0 ']'
- parm=http://ya.ru
- shift
- case "$parm" in
- '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
- '[' -z '' ']'
- unset XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL
- '[' 0 -lt 1 ']'
- xdg_redirect_output=' > /dev/null 2> /dev/null'
- '[' xhttp://ya.ru '!=' x ']'
- url=
- '[' 1 -gt 0 ']'
- parm=http://ya.ru
- shift
- case "$parm" in
- '[' -n '' ']'
- url=http://ya.ru
- '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
- '[' -z http://ya.ru ']'
- detectDE
- unset GREP_OPTIONS
- '[' -n Unity ']'
- case "${XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP}" in
- '[' x = x ']'
- '[' x '!=' x ']'
- '[' xthis-is-deprecated '!=' x ']'
- DE=gnome
- '[' xgnome = x ']'
- '[' xgnome = x ']'
- '[' xgnome = xgnome ']'
- which gnome-default-applications-properties
- DE=gnome3
- '[' xgnome3 = x ']'
- DEBUG 2 'Selected DE gnome3'
- '[' -z '' ']'
- return 0
- case "${BROWSER}" in
- case "$DE" in
- open_gnome3 http://ya.ru
- gvfs-open --help
- gvfs-open http://ya.ru
- '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
- exit_success
- '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
- exit 0

В других браузерах все прекрасно работает. Кроме того в параметрах системы google chrome не может быть выбран браузером по умолчанию, возможно ubuntu не видит его или видит его неправильно.

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к тексту вопроса: 1. полный вывод команды `$ bash -x xdg-open http://ya.ru` 2. открылся ли при этом в каком-нибудь бразуре указанный url? 3. в каком именно браузере?